# Square root of a squared number: $\sqrt{a^2} = a \in \mathbb R$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

**True or False**

$$a\in \mathbb R\implies \sqrt{a^2} = a$$

**a** positive or negative, will always be equal to **a**, so for me it is true, but the teacher says that the expression is false, but I can not understand why?

Comment: Indeed, $\sqrt {a^2}=|a|$.  Note:  I don't think you know what "simplicial" means.

Comment: Hi @lulu, what do you say by the tag? I wanted to say simplification of expressions, but I did not find something similar

Comment: Maybe [algebra-precalculus]?

Comment: @BrianVanegasParra This is *precalculus*, so the [algebra-precalculus] tag should be the way to go. In fact, when you hover over the tag, you can read a description, and it is rather apparent that [simplicial-stuff] has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Suppose $a = -3$.  Then is it true that $\sqrt{(-3)^2} = \sqrt 9 = -3 = a$?

Comment: for me **a** is always a real number, reason to prove that it is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

$0 > a \in \Bbb R, \tag 1$

then

$a^2 > 0, \tag 2$

whence

$0 < \sqrt{a^2} = \vert a \vert \ne a < 0 \tag 3$

***Note:*** for $r > 0$, it is generally understood that $\sqrt r > 0$.

(See comment below that the function $\sqrt \cdot$ is defined for *non-negative* arguments.) ***End of Note.***

Comment: my teacher particularized the value of a = -4 to say that the expression is false, but I think it is wrong:
$$ \sqrt{-4}^2 = \sqrt{16} = 4 $$
4 ≠ a ????? 
I do not understand your argument, for me to be a or -a $$∈ {R}$$

Comment: @BrianVanegasParra:  with $a = -4$, $\sqrt {a^2} = \sqrt{(-4)^2} = \sqrt{16} = 4 \ne -4$, so $\sqrt{a^2} \ne a$ in this case.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but -4 is a real number, can I prove that it is true because its result is in the real numbers?

Comment: @BrianVanegasParra:  of course $-4 \in \Bbb R$; it's just that not all real numbers have real square roots; the function $\sqrt \cdot$ is only defined for *non-negative* arguments.

Comment: Thank you, your comments were very helpful

Comment: @BrianVanegasParra:  my pleasure sir!

Comment: a can perfectly well be such that $a = 0$, then $\sqrt {a^2} = \sqrt{0} = |0| = 0$. $$0 \leq \sqrt{a^2} = \vert a \vert \geq 0$$

Comment: @amWhy:  of course we may perfectly well have $a = 0$ and your result clearly and cleanly follows, which is why I stipulated $a \ne 0$ in my answer, which begins with the line "If $0 > a$ . .  .

Comment: I realize you took care. Note: I added a reference to your comment in comments about the domain of definition for the square root "function" to be a function, because this point was missed in other answers here, and is an important response to "why" |a|....  You can remove it, or expand it.  I think you made the point well.  In any case +1

Comment: @amWhy:  A'all good.  I don't usually leave edits to my post alone, but I will in this case.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using a convention, which is that by $\sqrt{x}$ (for $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$) we intend the *positive* number $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha^2=x.$

It is a convention, we might take the negative one (which is $-\alpha$) but it would be pointless.

Back to your question, if you take $a<0,$ square it and take the square root you obtain a positive number, that thus can't be $a,$ which is negative.

In general you have that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|.$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the square root $\sqrt{x}$ of a real number $x\ge 0$ is the unique number $y\ge 0$ such that $y^2=x$.

Quite obviously there exist numbers $a\in\mathbb R$ with $a<0$. Those are *not* the square root of any number, because the square root is, by definition, not negative. However, the number $a^2$ *does* have a square root, as the square of a negative number is positive, and furthermore $(-a)^2 = a^2$. And when $a<0$ then $-a>0$, and therefore we have
$$\sqrt{a^2} = \begin{cases}
a & \text{for } a\ge 0\\
-a & \text{for } a<0
\end{cases}$$
Now there is a function that is defined exactly that way, and that is the absolute value function $|x|$. Therefore the above equation can be written as
$$\sqrt{a^2} = |a|.$$

Comment: Thanks, but the in between part is just another definition for $|a|$.  Hence I'd argue $\sqrt {a^2} = |a|$, and then elaborate, that means, $|a| = \begin{cases}
a & \text{for } a\ge 0\\
-a & \text{for } a<0
\end{cases}$

Comment: @amWhy: The case definition is more elementary: It works for any totally ordered abelian group.

Comment: Next time an asker asks about |a| in a post tagged "order theory" and "abelian groups", I'll link them to your answer.  Here, I think either you or me is nitpicking; in any case, I found the original answers to the duplicated posts, and others here, far more helpful than yours.

Answer (score 1):

Think about this ...

$2 = \sqrt{4} \neq \sqrt{-2}\sqrt{-2} = \sqrt{2}i\sqrt{2}i = -\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2} = -2$.

Comment: I stopped so much in if it was **a** real number or not, that neglects equality

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question, @Brian

Comment: @amWhy Why not?

Comment: @amWhy Thank you, your comments were very helpful

Comment: You're welcome, @BrianVanegasParra  I don't know what happened to my comments though?  I hope you had a chance to read them.

Answer (score 1):

Since for $x\ge 0$ we define

$$y=\sqrt {x} \iff y^2=x \quad y\ge 0,$$

we have that

$$\forall a\in \mathbb{R} \implies \sqrt {a^2}=|a|.$$

Indeed, for example, for $a=\pm 2$

- $\sqrt {2^2}=\sqrt 4=2$
- $\sqrt {(-2)^2}=\sqrt 4=2$

Comment: The second statement doesn't follow from the first. We have, rather, for real $x, y$, $ y= \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  We don't need to know that $y^2 = x$

Comment: @amWhy I mean that by definition for $x\ge 0$ we define $y=:\sqrt x$ the real number $y\ge 0$ such that $y^2=x$. From that definition $\sqrt {a^2}=|a|$ follows. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are not "wrong", just made things a tad more complicated than need be. But I have not said, nor voted, to suggest you are wrong.  It was merely the seventh or eight time it had already been said.  This is just me, I'm sure, but I prefer not to repeat an answer that's already been repeated, and said in just about every possible permutations of words in the definition as possible to express the same definition.

Comment: @amWhy Without the first definition it is not so clear why $\sqrt {(-a)^2}=-a$ is not an acceptable conclusion, for that I gave that explanation. For the duplicates I think that it is unavoidable that after many years some topic is presented many times as a question and as related answers. For expert users that can be bad thing but for many contributors those topics are discussed for the first time. I think that the system for the closure of duplicates works very well and allow us to behave as we prefer. Thanks, Bye.

Answer (score 0):

For $a \in \mathbb R$, $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$ by definition, so $\sqrt{(-5)^2} = |-5| =5.$

Comment: Well, not quite the definition. There is a very specific reason why this identity holds (which of course follows from the definition of $\sqrt\bullet$).

Comment: for me **a** is always a real number, reason to prove that it is true

Comment: actually, it can be be always visualluzed as distance of point from (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

For $b>0$, the symbol $\sqrt b$ means, by definition, the *nonnegative* solution of $x^2=b$.

The solutions of $x^2=b$ are $\pm\sqrt b$.

Comment: But the problem isn't $x^2 = b$: what is $b$?.  We are given $a \in \mathbb R$ (positive, negative, not complex).  Then the solution, for any real $a$ in \mathbb R$, $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$.

Answer (score 0):

Well it really should be

$$a \in \mathbb{R} \implies \sqrt{a^2} \in \{-a,a\}$$

as $(-a)^2=a^2$.

[I think your teacher was asking you to recognize the ambiguity, that both $-a$ and $a$--instead of only $a$--square to $a^2$.]

Comment: I think $\sqrt a$ is general taken to be positive for positive $a$.  So it's not really correct to say $\sqrt a \in \{-a, a \}$.  What *is* correct is $\pm \sqrt a \in \{-a, a\}$.  Cheers!

Comment: I am not positive that everyone follows that convention though: some may take $\sqrt{r}$ as *any* value that squares to $r$. I suspect the teacher really was asking the OP to recognize that $-a$ also squares to $a^2$. If I were writing a paper and it wasn't clear I would be explicit that by $\sqrt{r}$ for real positive $r$, I mean the *positive* real number that squares to $r$.

Comment: yes, it can be, but that does not exclude it from the real numbers

Comment: @Mike I fullt understand you point but according to the usual definition, it is not correct claim your answer. Indeed we have that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ and of course as $|a|^2=a$ and $(-|a|)^2=a$. That is the square root $\sqrt x$ of a non negative value $x\ge 0$ is the unique non negative value $y\ge 0$ such that $y^2=x$ andm of course $(-y)^2=x$.

Comment: These "easy" questions always seem to get the most debate. I think we can all agree that both $-a$ and $a$ square to the same thing, I think that was what the teacher was asking the student to recognize that, and that is reflected in my answer. [Even though I have a PhD I always forget the convention of the sign of $\sqrt{r}$ and I don't think I am the only one. In practice typically the author makes it explicit whether $\sqrt{r}$ is always nonnegative if it wasn't clear already.]

Answer (score 0):

The words we often say aren't quite precise. For example, we see $\sqrt{9}$, and say "the square root of $9$."  But actually $9$ has two square roots, namely $3$ and $-3$. What we should say when we see $\sqrt{9}$ is "the nonnegative square root of $9$" (also known as the principal square root of $9$).

In short, $\sqrt{x}$ for nonnegative $x$ means (always and only) the nonnegative square root of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

suppose a = -4

$$ a = -4 ⟹ \sqrt{-4}^2 = \sqrt{16} = 4 ≠ -4 $$

It is **false**